# I don't know how to add background at 2d animation

Tags: animation, export, image, 2d

I don't know how to add background at 2d animation, I tried to export an image but that happens.

[image: viewport screenshot]

Also when I press  <kbd>F12</kbd> for testing, I can't see the image (background)

[image: render screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Next time, please upload and add the images to your question so they don't go lost and visitors don't need to click external links.

Comment: I’ve done this before by using the image as a world background, but putting in window vectors instead of the generated coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Blender being a 3D program, there's not really a concept of 2D background in the 3D rendering. You could theoretically add a 2D background behind the rendered image via compositing nodes, but I guess you'd be more interested to see your background in the viewport as well.

So the solution is to literally add a 3D plane in the 3D space, textured with your background image.

From your outliner it looks like you have added your background as an [Empty Image object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/empties.html#bpy-types-object-empty-image). This kind of object is not renderable, as it is meant to be used only as reference content for creating assets, not for being actually rendered. You need a mesh object instead.

Turns out there's an [addon for importing images as planes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html). If you've never used it before, go to `Edit` menu > `Preferences` > `Addons` tab > search for `Images as planes` and enable this addon.

Then, go to `File` menu > `Import` > `Impage as plane` > browse to your image and select it, open the sidebar with <kbd>N</kbd> and set the materials settings to Emit. Then you can hit the `Import` button.

This will create a mesh plane with your texture on it. Move it around the scene however you like.

If you want it to fit the camera, there isn't an automated to do it AFAIK. Just eyeball it.